# How to copy multiple TBs of data between buckets with Cloud Functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'd like an automated way to copy very large datasets between Google Cloud Storage buckets -

Ex. Bucket A in Project A has 6 TB data in it. The individual files are as large as 300 GB. When a "done" marker file is uploaded to the bucket, all files need to be copied to Bucket B in Project B

I've been trying to solve this with 1st Gen Cloud Functions (cannot use 2nd) -

The Cloud Function checks for when the "done" file is uploaded to the bucket A. Then a python script uses google-cloud-storage to copy all files of the bucket A to bucket B

This is predictably failing due to the 9 minute timeout

Does anyone know a graceful way to automate this copy? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you absolutely need to use Cloud Functions v1?  There are likely other ways to get this done that don't involve Cloud Functions, as long as you're willing to trigger a different compute product to execute the copy that also doesn't have such a limiting timeout.

Comment: I might be able to use other tools! Is there a good alternative to cloud functions for this?

Comment: [Asking for recommendations for tools is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and will likely be closed.  I will say that your options for backend processing are nearly limitless and you could easily do some research for something that meets your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly answering your question - it's not possible to exceed the 9 minute timeout with Cloud Functions v1.  You don't really have alternative unless you're willing to split up and batch your transfers with multiple function invocations, which will be a lot of work (and won't help you if you have a single file to copy that always takes more than the timeout).

GCP and other cloud providers have many multiple other backend products that you can use that give you more flexibility on doing the copy.  A complete discussion of your options is off-topic for Stack Overflow.